# Find the most general types of the following lambda calculus terms

Tags: types, lambda, type-inference, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I am having trouble understand why these are the most general types for their respective Church numerals:

```
2 = λf.λx. f (f x) : (α → α) → α → α 

1 = λf.λx. f x : (α → β) → α → β

0 = λf.λx. x : β → α → α
```

I thought that all Church numerals had the same type :

```
(α → α) → α → α
```

Also how would I find a general type for the add operator

```
λm.λn.λf.λx. m f (n f x)
```

Any help would really be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the Church numeral for zero:

```
λf.λx. x : β → α → α
```

Looking only at `λf.λx.` part, one can deduce that we have a two-argument function, hence its type is `α → β → γ`, where `α` and `β` stand for arguments' types and `γ` stands for the result type. Now, the body `x` constraints the type further: our function's return type must be the same as its second argument's type. That results in `α → β → β`, or after renaming (α ↔ β): `λf.λx. x : β → α → α`. That's the most general type for zero, since we didn't use the fact that `f` should be a function, in fact, the Church zero numeral in *untyped* lambda calculus doesn't care: it just forgets it's first argument. And since `β` is just a placeholder, you can *specialize* it to `α → α`, which results in a more concrete type for zero -- `λf.λx. x : (α → α) → α → α`.

Let's look at `1`:

```
λf.λx. f x : (α → β) → α → β
```

Again, it's a two-argument function: `α → β → γ`, but this time (look at the body of `1`) we know the first argument `f` is a function, so `f` has some type `δ → ε`, which we should substitute for `α`: `(δ → ε) → β → γ`. Now, we know that we must be able to apply `f` to `x`, which means that the type of `x` and the type of `f`'s argument must be equal: `δ` = `β`, thus, we've reached `(β → ε) → β → γ`. But that is not all we know, `f x` has type `ε`, and our numeral returns `f x`, applying this information, we get `ε` = `γ`. Incorporating all that, we arrive at `(β → γ) → β → γ`, or after renaming: `λf.λx. f x : (α → β) → α → β`. Again we didn't use any information about our usage intensions, that's why we've got the most general type and, of course, it can be specialized (by the restriction `β` = `α`) to `λf.λx. f x : (α → α) → α → α`.

It's `2`'s turn now:

```
λf.λx. f (f x) : (α → α) → α → α
```

I won't repeat all the steps this time, but (as an intermediate step) we can arrive at `λf.λx. f (f x) : (α → β) → α → β`. Notice, however, that this time we're feeding `f`'s result into itself: `f (f x)`, and this means that `f`'s input and output types must be equal, thus `β` = `α`, and the most general type is `λf.λx. f (f x) : (α → α) → α → α` this time.

**(*)** Note that Church's `3`, `4`, etc. have the same most general type as `2` do, because multiple function applications don't give us any additional information to specialize the type further.

---

As for the addition function `λm.λn.λf.λx. m f (n f x)`, let me be a bit more terse:

- Assume the expression has type `α → β → γ → δ → ε`.
- `m` is a function of 2 arguments: `α` must be restricted to `α' → α'' → α'''`
- Same for `n`: `β` must be restricted to `β' → β'' → β'''`
- `m`'s and `n`'s first argument has the same type, which is the type of `f`: `α'` = `β'` = `γ`
- `n`'s second argument's type is `δ`
- `n`'s result type equals to `m`'s second argument type: `β'''` = `α''`
- Let's combine all the above knowledge for `n : γ → δ → α''`
- Same for `m : γ → α'' → ε`
- Hence, the result type is `(γ → α'' → ε) → (γ → δ → α'') → γ → δ → ε`

Let's rename the variables to make it look a bit prettier:

the most general type for `λm.λn.λf.λx. m f (n f x)` is

`(β → γ → ε) → (β → α → γ) → β → α → ε`.

Let's check that it can be specialized to what one would expect to be a binary operation on Church numerals
(`β` = `α → α`, `γ` = `α`, `ε` = `α`):

`((α → α) → α → α) → ((α → α) → α → α) → (α → α) → α → α`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been very helpful, I finally understand!

Comment: in  `λm.λn.λf.λx. m f (n f x)` why you didn't expand the type of `f`? I am really getting confused at this point since `f` is a function that takes 1 argument that is the type of `x` or the `n`'s result type. I though that for `f`: `y` should be restricted to `α''`-> `y''`

Comment: @alixander Because it would not get us the most *general* type. If you try checking this with Haskell's GHCi interpreter using this query `:t \m n f x -> m f (n f x)`, or an in an OCaml's toplevel with `fun m n f x -> m f (n f x);;`, you'll arrive at the same result as in my hand-written version (modulo naming).

Comment: @AntonTrunov i know the result is correct. I tried it already in haskell, but i am still not understanding the why the type of `f` is not getting expanded!

Comment: @alixander `f` is not applied to anything, so there is no reason for the type inference engine to consider it a function. What we got is more general, it’s basically a composition of two functions with a common (to both of them) “environment” `f`. HTH

Comment: @AntonTrunov why do u consider that `f` is not applied to anything ?

Comment: @alixander Could the source of your confusion be the way you parse the expression? In expression `m f (n f x)`, `f` is not applied to anything. Only `m` and `n` are. `n` is applied to two arguments -- `f` and `x` and `m` is applied to `f` and `n f x`.